# Mathematica shut down when loading codes

Tags: front-end

Yesterday my mathematica code can ran.
However, now whenever I open it in Mathematica, Mathematica shut down immediately...I tried other files, and they can be opened in Mathematica.

Is it possible that the file is damaged (in some sense?)? What are the possible ways I can reopen it in Mathematica?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can open it with a text editor to check it. Copy and paste the relevant code in  a new notebook. Worked for me once.

Comment: What is the format of the code file? `.wl`, `.wxf`, `.mx` or `.nb`?

Comment: My file name (.nb) contained "[" and "]". The problem has been solved by removing the two symbols "[" and "]" from the file name (although I cannot understand why). Thanks all for you suggestions.